# How to hide the cursor, if only background is displayed?

Tags: html, css, cursor, background-image

I wanted to hide the Cursor if the only the background is displayed in HTML/CSS.
but for some reason it doesn't work properly, it displays the cursor over the background.

my code:

```css
body {
  background: url('https://miro.medium.com/max/10368/1*o8tTGo3vsocTKnCUyz0wHA.jpeg') #000000 top left no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: none
}
```

```html
<body scroll="no" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
</body>
```

Comment: do you want to remove the cursor for your page? I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: the cursor should be invisible/removed, but the html-body is empty, except for the background

Answer (score 1):

I think from your markup, you're looking to hide the cursor outside image. You can make use of CSS property `cursor: none` to achieve this besides the sections you need cursor.

The below example hides cursor outside the image:

```css
<style type="text/css">
    .hide-cursor { cursor:none; }
    .show-cursor { cursor:auto }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
  <body class="hide-cursor">
   <h1>These contents get no cursor visibility</h1>
   <p>These contents get no cursor visibility</p>
   <div class="show-cursor">
     <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg" />
   </div>
   <h1>These contents get no cursor visibility</h1>
   <p>These contents get no cursor visibility</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you look like hiding the cursor from the entire page except the sections you need, use this CSS which applies to entire page, and use `show-cursor` class shown above in the tags you wish to retain cursor visibility.

```css
html * {cursor:none}
```